# Interaction between Java app and native daemon - Parcel.readException

Tags: android, android-binder

I'm working on a requirement where the Java app need to interact with native daemon. The Java app issues command such as Start, Stop, and many others. The native daemon handles these requests and sends the response back to the Java app.
I'm using the binder mechanism to interact between the Java app and native daemon.

However I'm seeing a fatal exception while handling the response from the native daemon:

```
--------- beginning of crash
02-27 21:07:58.507  3401  3401 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 21:07:58.507  3401  3401 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.symbol.demosettings, PID: 3401
02-27 21:07:58.507  3401  3401 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } in com.symbol.demosettings.SettingsActivity$GeneralPreferenceFragment$1@4f51a41
02-27 21:07:58.507  3401  3401 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$-android_app_LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args_52497(LoadedApk.java:1323)
02-27 21:07:58.507  3401  3401 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.-$Lambda$aS31cHIhRx41653CMnd4gZqshIQ.$m$7(Unknown Source:4)
02-27 21:07:58.507  3401  3401 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.-$Lambda$aS31cHIhRx41653CMnd4gZqshIQ.run(Unknown Source:39)
02-27 21:07:58.507  3401  3401 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
02-27 21:07:58.507  3401  3401 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-27 21:07:58.507  3401  3401 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
02-27 21:07:58.507  3401  3401 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6501)
02-27 21:07:58.507  3401  3401 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-27 21:07:58.507  3401  3401 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
02-27 21:07:58.507  3401  3401 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
02-27 21:07:58.507  3401  3401 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown exception code: 47 msg null
02-27 21:07:58.507  3401  3401 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2020)
02-27 21:07:58.507  3401  3401 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1950)
02-27 21:07:58.507  3401  3401 E AndroidRuntime:    at yancy.github.nativeservice.IDemoService$Stub$Proxy.AddNumber(IDemoService.java:97)
02-27 21:07:58.507  3401  3401 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.symbol.demosettings.SettingsActivity$GeneralPreferenceFragment.bindDemoService(SettingsActivity.java:576)
02-27 21:07:58.507  3401  3401 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.symbol.demosettings.SettingsActivity$GeneralPreferenceFragment.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
02-27 21:07:58.507  3401  3401 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.symbol.demosettings.SettingsActivity$GeneralPreferenceFragment$1.onReceive(SettingsActivity.java:377)
02-27 21:07:58.507  3401  3401 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$-android_app_LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args_52497(LoadedApk.java:1313)
02-27 21:07:58.507  3401  3401 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 9 more
02-27 21:07:58.511  1585  1604 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.symbol.demosettings/.SettingsActivity
```

The snippet of SettingsActivity.java that interacts with the antive daemon is below:

```
private BroadcastReceiver WifiStateChangedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int extraWifiState = intent.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE ,
                                                WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN);
        switch (extraWifiState) {
        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED:
            bindDemoService();
            break;
        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLING:
            break;
        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN:
            break;
        }
    }
};

private void bindDemoService() {
    try {
        IBinder b = ServiceManager.getService("yancy.github.nativeservice.IDemoService");
        if(b != null) {
            final IDemoService service =
                    IDemoService.Stub.asInterface(b);
            if(service != null) {
                Log.d("DEMOSERVICE", "AddNumber(23, 24): " + service.AddNumber(1, 2));
                Log.d("DEMOSERVICE", "MaxNumber(23, 24): " + service.MaxNumber(10, 11));
                Log.d("DEMOSERVICE", "MaxNumber(33, 24): " + service.MaxNumber(20, 21));
            } else {
                Log.d("DEMOSERVICE", "MainActivity asInterface fail.");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("DEMOSERVICE", "MainActivity get native service fail.");
        }
    } catch(RemoteException e) {
        Log.d("DEMOSERVICE", "ERROR:" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The corresponding AIDL is given below (IDemoService.aidl):

```
package yancy.github.nativeservice;

interface IDemoService {
    int AddNumber(int a, int b);
    int MaxNumber(int a, int b);
}
```

The native daemon part is below:

DemoService.cpp:

```
#include <binder/IServiceManager.h>
#include <binder/IPCThreadState.h>  
#include "IDemoService.h"  
#include "DemoService.h"

#define LOG_NDEBUG 0
#define LOG_TAG "DEMOSERVICE"  

#include <utils/Log.h>  


int DemoService::AddNumber(int a,int b)
{
    ALOGD("DemoService AddNumber a:%d, b:%d\n", a, b);
    return a + b;
}

int DemoService::MaxNumber(int a,int b)
{
    ALOGD("DemoService MaxNumber a:%d, b:%d\n", a, b);
    return a > b ? a : b;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)  
{  
    DemoService::instance();  

    ProcessState::self()->startThreadPool();  
    IPCThreadState::self()->joinThreadPool();  

    return 0;  
}
```

IDemoService.cpp:

```
#define LOG_NDEBUG 0
#define LOG_TAG "DEMOSERVICE"  

#include <utils/Log.h>  

#include "IDemoService.h"

using namespace android;

class BpDemoService : public BpInterface<IDemoService>
{
public:
    BpDemoService(const sp<IBinder>& impl) : BpInterface<IDemoService>(impl){};
    int AddNumber(int a, int b)
    {
        ALOGD("BpDemoService AddNumber a:%d , b:%d\n", a, b);

        Parcel data;  
        data.writeInterfaceToken(IDemoService::getInterfaceDescriptor());  
        data.writeInt32(a);
        data.writeInt32(b);

        Parcel reply;  
        remote()->transact(ADD_NUMBER, data, &reply);
        if (reply.readExceptionCode() != 0) {
            ALOGD("IDemoService got an exception %i", reply.readExceptionCode());
            return -1;
        }

        return reply.readInt32();
    }

    int MaxNumber(int a, int b)
    {
        ALOGD("BpDemoService MaxNumber a:%d , b:%d\n", a, b);
        Parcel data;  
        data.writeInterfaceToken(IDemoService::getInterfaceDescriptor());  
        data.writeInt32(a);
        data.writeInt32(b);

        Parcel reply;  
        remote()->transact(MAX_NUMBER, data, &reply);
        if (reply.readExceptionCode() != 0) {
            ALOGD("IDemoService got an exception %i", reply.readExceptionCode());
            return -1;
        }

        return reply.readInt32();
    }

};

IMPLEMENT_META_INTERFACE(DemoService, SERVICE_NAME);


status_t BnDemoService::onTransact(uint32_t code,const Parcel & data,Parcel * reply, uint32_t flags)
{
    switch(code)
    {
        case ADD_NUMBER:
        {
            CHECK_INTERFACE(IDemoService, data, reply);
            int ret = AddNumber(data.readInt32(), data.readInt32());
            ALOGD("BpDemoService ADD_NUMBER ret:%d\n", ret);
            reply->writeInt32(ret);
            return NO_ERROR;
        }
        case MAX_NUMBER:
        {
            CHECK_INTERFACE(IDemoService, data, reply);
            int ret = MaxNumber(data.readInt32(), data.readInt32());
            ALOGD("BpDemoService MAX_NUMBER ret:%d\n", ret);
            reply->writeInt32(ret);
            return NO_ERROR;
        }
        default:
            return BBinder::onTransact(code, data, reply, flags);
    }
}
```

DemoService.h:

```
#ifndef __DEMO_SERVICE_H__
#define __DEMO_SERVICE_H__

#include "IDemoService.h"


class DemoService : public BnDemoService
{
public:
    int AddNumber(int a, int b);
    int MaxNumber(int a, int b);   
    static void instance()
    {
        defaultServiceManager()->addService(String16(SERVICE_NAME), new DemoService());
    };
};

#endif /* __DEMO_SERVICE_H__ */
```

IDemoService.h:

```
#ifndef __I_DEMO_SERVICE_H__
#define __I_DEMO_SERVICE_H__


#include <utils/RefBase.h>
#include <binder/IInterface.h>
#include <binder/Parcel.h>

using namespace android;

#define SERVICE_NAME    "yancy.github.nativeservice.IDemoService"

enum {
    ADD_NUMBER = IBinder::FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION,
    MAX_NUMBER
};


class IDemoService : public IInterface
{
public:
    DECLARE_META_INTERFACE(DemoService);

    virtual int AddNumber(int a, int b) = 0;
    virtual int MaxNumber(int a, int b) = 0;
};


class BnDemoService : public BnInterface<IDemoService>
{
public:
    virtual status_t onTransact(uint32_t code, const Parcel& data, Parcel* reply, uint32_t flags = 0); 
};

#endif /* __I_DEMO_SERVICE_H__ */
```